# Array search problem

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

```
$comedy = 'comedy, drama, thriller, action';

$array = array('action', 'fantasy', 'war', 'comedy', 'romance', 'drama', 'thriller');
```

I need to find the key words from each variable `$comedy`.

I need:

```
3
5
6
0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following portion of code :

```
$comedy = 'comedy, drama, thriller, action';
$array = array('action', 'fantasy', 'war', 'comedy', 'romance', 'drama', 'thriller');

foreach (explode(', ', $comedy) as $word) {
    $index = array_search($word, $array);
    var_dump($index);
}
```

Which gives me the following output :

```
int 3
int 5
int 6
int 0
```

Basically :

- As your words in the `$comedy` variables are always separated by the same pattern `', '`, you can use [**`explode()`**](https://www.php.net/explode) to get an array that contains those words.
- Then, iterating over those words, you just have to call [**`array_search()`**](https://www.php.net/array_search) to get their position in your `$array` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$comedy = 'comedy, drama, thriller, action';

$array = array('action', 'fantasy', 'war', 'comedy', 'romance', 'drama', 'thriller');

$tags = explode(', ', $comedy);

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    echo array_search($tag, $array) . "\n";
}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find (and print) each of the indexes you want easily:

```
foreach (explode(', ', $comedy) as $keyword) {
    echo array_find($keyword, $array);
}
```

If you want to associate each keyword with the index, you can do it this way:

```
$words = explode(', ', $comedy);
$indexes = array_map(
             $words, 
             function($word) use ($array) { return array_find($keyword, $array); } 
$assoc = array_combine($words, $indexes);

print_r($assoc);
```

The above requires PHP >= 5.3 for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Why is comedy just a string?

I would just make comedy an array also and then make a loop that checks each value in the comedy against each value in the array.